# Hiding zero entities after a relationship

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my linq statement. Basicly i don't want to see zero items. Yes i realize the situation why it looks like this, but i need to see > 0 items. How can i do that?

Contents.Select( x=> new { RelatedContents = x.RelatedContents } )

[image]

Comment: If you actually need a flat list instead of nested lists use SelectMany

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Count` or `Any`

Using Count:

```
Contents.Select( x=> new { RelatedContents = x.RelatedContents } ).Where(c => c.RelatedContents.Count() > 0);
```

Using Any:

```
Contents.Select( x=> new { RelatedContents = x.RelatedContents } ).Where(c => c.RelatedContents.Any());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Contents.Select( x=> new { RelatedContents = x.RelatedContents } )
   .Where(y => y.RelatedContents.Any());
```